# Set page numbers in pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have code for the pagination using jquery. Now i dosen't want to show all the page buttons. I want to create pagination like below screenshot. Any solution for that?[image]

```
var page = 1
var pagesize = 25
var links = Math.ceil(dataListings.length / pagesize); 
for(var i = 0; i < links; i++){
    var pagnm = i+1;
    Pageination = Pageination+'<li><a href="#" onclick="LoadPaginationdata(this.id);" id="Pagination_'+pagnm+'">'+pagnm+'</a></li>';
}
```

Right now it show me like this.
[image]

Comment: Any answer for these?

Comment: Creating pagination like images shown isn't simple and need to write more code. I think it it better to use plugin for it.

Comment: you can try this http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/